# Jenkins Deploy to IIS Remote Server through Archive Artifact

Tags: jenkins, iis, visual-studio-2013, remote-server, php-ziparchive

I have successfully create a `.zip` file (`visual studio 2013 project`) and transfer it to the remote server through `ArtifactDeployer` and Archive the Artifacts in `Jenkins`.

However, I am stuck on what to do next. How to actually deploy the archived file to the `IIS` in the remote server?

Answer (score 0):

so I finally got my own solution to deploy. Turns out my MSBuild Build File should contain the .publishproj instead of the .sln